# TypeError when passing a variable from one function to another in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have created 2 routes in my Flask App that takes in value from the first function and then the further operations are done in the second route but I get an Error stating `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`

Here is my routes.py file

```
@app.route('/getdetails', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getdetails():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        sems = request.form['sems']
        sems=int(sems)
        return render_template('new.html', n=name, s=sems)
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/getmarks', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getmarks():
    sems = request.args.get('sems')
    sems = int(sems)
    for i in range(sems):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            sgp = request.form['sgpa']
            sgp = int(sgp)
            marks.append(sgp)
    return render_template('getmarks.html', s=sems, marks=marks)
```

also here is the html template

```
{% block content %}

<form name="inputmarks" action="/getmarks" method="POST" style="width: 500px; margin: auto">
    {% for i in range(s) %}
        <label>SGPA {{i}}: </label>
        <input type="text" name="sgpa" class="form-control">
        <input type="submit" value="Lets Go">
    {% endfor %}    
</form>
```

The variable that I am requesting is of type 'int' but then when I print the type it shows me type as 'None Type'
How do I fix this?

variable sems is the value I am requesting for

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably arising from the second of these two lines:

```
sgp = request.form['sgpa']
sgp = int(sgp)
```

The submitted form is either empty or is not passing in the text value.

Try adding a print statement to check the first value of `sgp`

```
sgp = request.form['sgpa']
print('sgp =', sgp)
sgp = int(sgp)
```

Comment: ```sems = int(sems)```
```TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'```  this is what I get

Comment: Yes, when I enter the value I get that error in the form

Comment: I added that line in my code but now what I see is that when I enter the value inside the form the type of variable 'sems' chages from 'int' to 'NoneType' and the value of sgp is not getting printed due to this error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, most likely, in the begining of the `getmarks` function.

```
@app.route('/getmarks', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getmarks():
    sems = request.args.get('sems')
    sems = int(sems)
```

The way you are retrieving the value `sems` is, most likely, inconsistent with the the form you provided, and as a result, `sems` ends up being `None`, leading to the error in the call to `int()`.

Why does this happen? It is because posted data is not persistent across HTTP calls. The fact the the request handled by `getdetails` had the value of the field `sems` posted to it (I'm assuming it was, even though you did not provide the HTML form for that), does not mean that the same value would automatically get passed (either as a value in `form` or `args`) to subsequent HTTP requests, including the one handled by `getmarks`.

You need to embed any arguments posted from the first form, which you want to be posted by the second form, inside the second form. You can do this in several ways:

- You can create an invisible field in the second form, with the same name as it had in the first form, and set it to an initial value equal to the value posted by the first request. This would require that you access this field via the `form` property of the Flask request, rather than through the `args` property.
- You can make the value part of the form target as a GET-style argument. I would not recommend this method, though.

Comment: Hey, I tried everything possible, I am new to Flask and couldn't get the result, could you please make me understand this in a simple way or do you want me to post any piece of code in the question from my project?